# Input Value Substitution Outlook Actionable Messages not passing value

Tags: json, power-automate, adaptive-cards

So I am using this in Microsoft Flow to generate an actionable email in Outlook.
The card itself works properly and displays properly in Outlook. The problem is the input value substitution for the Action.Http.

It is literally passing "{{newVendorNames.value}}", "{{newVendorDocs.value}}" and "{{existingVendorAction.value}}" instead of the values I enter into the adaptive card. The values are all strings.

Specific line is `"body": "{\"newVendorNames\":\"{{newVendorNames.value}}\",\"newVendorDocs\":\"{{newVendorDocs.value}}\",\"existingVendorAction\":\"{{existingVendorAction.value}}\"}"`

Did I miss something? Is this a bug?

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"originator":"ORIGINATOR ID",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "size": "medium",
        "weight": "bolder",
        "text": "Month End Close - Response"
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "In order to complete our month-end close, please go through any sections that apply for the current month.",
        "wrap": true
    }
],
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
        "title": "New Vendor",
        "card": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Complete this section **only if** a new vendor or vendors began work in the current month.",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "color": "attention",
                    "size": "medium"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Input.Text",
                    "id": "newVendorNames",
                    "placeholder": "Enter the names of the vendors that began work in the current month.",
                    "isMultiline": true
                },
                {
                    "type": "Input.Toggle",
                    "title": "I have an invoice/SOW/Contract,etc.",
                    "id": "newVendorDocs",
                    "valueOn": "Yes",
                    "valueOff": "No"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
        "title": "Existing Vendors",
        "card": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Complete this section **only if** an existing vendor has performed services in the current month.",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "color": "attention",
                    "size": "medium"
                },
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Have all invoices, for work performed in the current month, been submitted to AP?",
                    "wrap": true
                },
                {
                    "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                    "choices": [
                        {
                            "title": "Yes all invoices have been submitted.",
                            "value": "No"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "No they have not been submitted and I have a copy of the invoice(s).",
                            "value": "Obtain invoices."
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "No they have not been submitted, I do not have a copy but I can estimate the cost.",
                            "value": "Dept owner can estimate accrual."
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "No they have not been submitted, I do not have a copy and I cannot estimate the cost.",
                            "value": "Dept owner cannot estimate accrual."
                        }
                    ],
                    "id": "existingVendorAction",
                    "style": "expanded"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Http",
        "title": "Submit Response",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Authorization",
                "value": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Type",
                "value": "application/json"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://logic.azure.com:443/DELETED",
        "isPrimary": true,
        "body": "{\"newVendorNames\":\"{{newVendorNames.value}}\",\"newVendorDocs\":\"{{newVendorDocs.value}}\",\"existingVendorAction\":\"{{existingVendorAction.value}}\"}"
    }
],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.0"
```

}

Comment: Did the answer work for you? I’ve been banging my head against the desk all week w/same problem. Solution of adding \n did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this JSON:

```
"body": "{\n\"newVendorNames\": \"{{newVendorNames.value}}\",\n\"newVendorDocs\": \"{{newVendorDocs.value}}\",\n\"existingVendorAction\": \"{{existingVendorAction.value}}\"\n}"
```

You forgot the `\n`